# Using Flags in my own C# control such as the settings in UserAccountControl in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, class-design, bitarray

I have been working with System.DirectoryServices for a while in a project involving Active Directory. I am curious on the implementation of the UserAccountControl property to  control the attributes of a particular account. If I wanted to implement settings in my own applications using a combination of bytes to determine the state of x or y setting, **how would I go about doing this in C#?** Say that I would like to implement a useraccountcontrol property on my own class and I want to use a combination of bytes to determine which permissions the account should have.

Here is the way it is modified in Active Directory:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144

and here is the place with the object definition:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680832%28VS.85%29.aspx

Edit:

Say that I have a User class of my own and I want to implement a property similar to the way UserAccountControl is implemented in Active Directory. Let's say I want to have a set of four bytes storing the settings.

I want to use the last byte to determine the account status, 
0 = Account Inactive 1= Account Active 2=Account Expired 4=Some Other Status 8=Yet Another Status.

Then the next byte to the left I want to contain the account type: 
16=Admin Account, 32=Regular Account, 64=Guest Account, 128 = Other Account.

Then use the next byte to the left to set some other setting so that 
256 = something, 512 = something else, 1024 = something else, etc.

I would like to combine this to use bitwise combinations to set the account properties. I have the idea in my head, but I am not sure how to implement it, or if it even makes sense what I am trying to do.

Edit:
After receiving the answer and doing some more digging I found this link that talks more about setting Flags: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062.aspx

Comment: Sorry Whats your question? Do you want to know which combinations come out given a hex value?

Comment: I edited the question adding more information, perhaps it makes more sense now.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this, but my question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute in case someone knows how to link it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define a helper type:

```
[Flags]
public enum UserAccountControl {
    // values from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144
    Script = 0x0001,
    AccountDisabled = 0x0002,
    HomeDirRequired = 0x0008,
    Lockout = 0x0010,
    PasswordNotRequired = 0x0020,
    PasswordCantChange = 0x0040,
    EncryptedTextPasswordAllowed = 0x0080,
    TempDuplicateAccount = 0x0100,
    NormalAccount = 0x0200,
    InterDomainTrustAccount = 0x0800,
    WorkstationTrustAccount = 0x1000,
    ServerTrustAccount = 0x2000,
    DontExpirePassword = 0x10000,
    MnsLogonAccount = 0x20000,
    SmartcardRequired = 0x40000,
    TrustedForDelegation = 0x80000,
    Delegated = 0x100000,
    UseDesKeyOnly = 0x200000,
    DontReqPreauth = 0x400000,
    PasswordExpired = 0x800000,
    TrustedToAuthForDelegation = 0x1000000
}
```

You can cast between `int` and `enum` types (I'm assuming you know how to get one of these values as an integer).  Then you could manipulate values using the bitwise operators as follows:

```
void manipulateUserFlags(UserAccountControl uac) {
    // Set the SCRIPT flag (bitwise OR)
    uac |= UserAccountControl.Script;

    // Clear the ACCOUNTDISABLE flag (complement, bitwise AND)
    uac &= ~UserAccountControl.AccountDisabled;

    // Check for the HOMEDIR_REQUIRED flag (bitwise AND)
    if((uac & UserAccountControl.HomeDirRequired) != UserAccountControl.None) {
        // ...
    }

    // Toggle the NORMAL_ACCOUNT flag (bitwise XOR)
    uac ^= UserAccountControl.NormalAccount;

    // Check for several types of trust, and a required password
    if((uac & UserAccountControl.WorkstationTrustAccount
            & UserAccountControl.ServerTrustAccount
            & ~UserAccountControl.PasswordNotRequired) != UserAccountControl.None) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Those are the same bitwise operators that work for integers, but `enum` types are recommended in C# because they are more strongly-typed.  Bitwise manipulation of integers makes a lot more sense in C or C++, because you can test directly on integers in conditionals and because those languages aren't as strongly-typed anyway.

However, if you are going to be implementing this as part of a library, or doing these operations commonly, I'd consider putting more of a design around it, with several `enum`-based properties that represent groups of similar settings, and `int ToADValue` and `UserAccountControl FromADValue` methods.  This would give you a clear place to put any validation logic, and it would make code that manipulates these properties even more readable.